How to download a remote directory list and not its contents?
From a remote directory I have to automatically download a file of which I know part of the name, only (e.g. "file-vers.1.2.3.zip", where the version number is the unknown part).
Since neither wget nor curl accept the '*' special character in the paths, I suppose I need to download the directory contents first (the equivalent of ls or dir), parse it, extract the file name I need, check its version is newer that what I already have, and pass it to either wget or curl.
If there is no quicker way that this, my question is: how can I download the directory contents from an HTTPS and an SFTP repository?

AFAIK there is no notion of listable directories in HTTP(S). For SFTP you can use sshfs and then work with the files as if they were local: cp and globbing should work.

have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/a/64971695 ?

In case of SFTP you can use ls to get the listing. But will be much easier to use command mget:
mget file-vers*.zip

This command will get all the files based on the wildcard.

What is this mget command?

@cachius, mget is used to get multiply files (using wildcard).

@cachius Technically, in sftp the mget is just an alias to get. It does not have any special ("multiple") functionality. The get works the same way (supports wildcards). The mget is there probably only for those who are used to get/mget distinction from old ftp. Though admittedly, it's not really clear what client does poster use in the first place (if it is sftp at all).
